# SQLAlchemy - Help understanding Query + Join + Filter?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm struggling to understand how SQL Alchemy functions, specifically with respect to a filter, then outer join. I have two simple tables:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "posts"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey('users.id'),
        index=True,
        nullable=True)
    privacy = db.Column(db.Text, default="private")


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
```

My goal is to filter `Post` for all posts marked as `private`, then join with `User` to add the `username`.

**Attempt #1**

```
    public_posts = GeneratedImages.query.filter_by(privacy="public")\
        .outerjoin(User)\
        .all()
    logger.info(public_images[0].username)

> AttributeError: 'Post' object has no attribute 'username'
```

**Attempt #2**

```
    public_posts = db.session.query(
        Post
    ).outerjoin(
        (User, Post.user_id == User.id)
    ).filter(
        Post.privacy == "public"
    ).all()
> AttributeError: 'Post' object has no attribute 'username'
```

**Attempt #3**

```
    public_posts = db.session.query(Post, User).outerjoin(
        User, Post.user_id == User.id
    ).filter_by(privacy="public").all()
> AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'privacy'
```

What am I doing wrong with this simple filter and join?

Comment: 1.and 3. attempt are not proper, you should not use `filter_by` with joins. However 2. attempt looks ok. Are you getting exception at this query or when you exploit results of the query (attributes access)?

Comment: @jorzel , let me check on 2. In the interim, can you explain why one should not use `filter_by` with joins? What if I want to first filter (to reduce the amount of data considered) before joining?

Comment: But it is still a single query. You are filtering and joining in one query (It is not filter query first, and join query after it). Sequence of `join` and `filter` does not matter (You can check your output statement)